# Get column number of the first colum visible to the right of the Freeze Panes column?

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to find out, via formula rather than VBA if possible, which column is the first visible column to the right of the Freeze Panes column - ie: it has not yet been scrolled "under" the frozen column.  The scrolled under ones aren't technically "Hidden" or "filtered" so I can't look for the first unhidden column.  Is there some way to recognise if a column has been scrolled under/behind the frozen column or is still visible?
As a last resort - can it be recognised by VBA?
Trawled the web - no luck yet.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, Gotcha. Try this:

```
Sub visible()

Dim a As Range, f As Range
Dim b As Integer, c As Integer

Set a = Excel.ActiveWindow.VisibleRange
b = a.Columns.Count                     'number of columns shown on screen
c = a.Columns(a.Columns.Count).Column   'column number of last column on screen

ActiveCell = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, c - b + 1).Address

End Sub
```

This would get you the column letter + row number of the first column in the same row of your active cell.
Hope this is helpfull.

Comment: Thanks again P.b.  As brilliant as that is, and I can adapt it to my needs, I was trying to avoid creating a macro enabled workbook, hence the question about whether it could be done as a formula and not in VBA.  Thanks for you time an effort.  I will check with the user as to whether the function she was after is important enough to go ahead with a macro.

Comment: Unless you have all Columns in the same width and the screen size is always identical it's only possible by macro. Else you could work with offset function.

Answer (score 0):

If the Freeze Panes column letter is "G" the first next column would be "G" + 1 = "H".
If you want to show he value of the first row in that column type `=H1` in the first row where you want to show the value. You can drag the formula down to show the value for the next row.

Not sure if that's what you mean.

Comment: Hi P.b - thanks for your time.  Further to your scenario:- If I Freeze at column G, yes of course column H is next.  But now I scroll to the right and column I is next to Col G, scroll further and it's Column J - can I tell with a formula or with VBA which is the first visible column after the Frozen column?